# GLSL rendering more textures than texture units available

Tags: opengl, glsl

Say if you have loaded a 3d model which has 25 textures, but you have a limit of 8 texture units. What is the most simplest / quickest way to render all the textures. I assume would be something like...

1) Load textures
2) bind texture texture to shader texture unit
3) render
4) loop to 2) until all textures rendered

I understand bind is a costly process so unsure if there is a better way or if my theory is correct...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all (or at least some) of your textures have the same size, you can use array textures. You create them with:

```
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, ...);
```

Where the `depth` argument would go for a 3D texture, you pass in the number of textures in your array (aka "layers"), and as always NULL for the last argument if you only want to allocate the memory. If you use OpenGL 4.2 or newer, you can also use `glTexStorage3D()` to allocate the texture memory.

You can then use `glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, ...)` to store the data for each of your textures in the array.

In your shader, you use variables of type `sampler2DArray` for array textures, and sample them with 3 texture coordinates, where the 3rd "coordinate" determines which layer is sampled, corresponding to the index into your array.

An entirely different approach that is sometimes employed is to use larger 2D textures, and store each of your actual textures as part of this larger texture. You can then control which of your textures is sampled by using the corresponding range of texture coordinates. Say if you had stored 4 textures of the same size in a single texture with twice the width and height, you would sample your first texture with texture coordinates in the range (0 .. 0.5, 0.0 .. 0.5), the second texture with (0.0 .. 0.5, 0.5 .. 1.0), the third with (0.5 .. 1.0, 0.0 .. 0.5), and the forth with (0.5 .. 1.0, 0.5 .. 1.0). This method is often called a "texture atlas".

Comment: Thanks, the images in question are all of different sizes in my case, and the 3d models already have the UV's set as per each image (models coming from external source e.g. clara.io).

Comment: @Equinox2000: you can also use the texure array approach if the texture sizes differ. One strategy would be to create the TA with the biggest width and height occuring. This can be extended to use a set of TAs for different sizes to not waste too much space. The tex coords will have to be recalculated in any case. And you can't use TAs with the fixed function pipeline anyway.

Comment: Cool idea, but there is one catch: the devices that have the most stringent texture unit count limits (low-cost OpenGL ES devices which often sport the minimum 8 units) are also the least likely to support EXT_texture_array: here are [OpenGL stats: 84%](http://opengl.gpuinfo.org/gl_extensions.php) and [OpenGL ES Stats: 3%](http://opengles.gpuinfo.org/gles_extensions.php).  It's OK though if your target doesn't include ES.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is meant as a side note to Reto Koradi's answer, and I think his answer is more relevant. However, I want to add that with really modern GPUs, there is [`GL_ARB_bindless_texture`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/bindless_texture.txt)
which allows you to use as much textures as you can fit into the memory, completelly bypassing any of the GL "texture units".

Currently, this extension is not part of core OpenGL, and it is supported only on NVidia GPUs since the "Kepler" architceture and on AMD GPUs since the "Graphics Core Next" architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are discussing glsl, I think it is worth pointing out that the number of Texture Image Units is actually separate from the number of discrete textures you can apply in a pass.

GL 3.3, for example, guarantees 48 TIUs (16 for each stage in the pipeline)... those 48 units allow you enough places to bind textures so that you can use a set of 16 *different* textures in your Vertex, Geometry and Fragment shaders. This does ***not***, however, mean that you can sample 48 different textures in your fragment shader.

There is a per-stage limit to the number of textures you can sample in a shader invocation (16 *minimum*, and it may not be the same limit for each stage). There is also an aggregate limit that applies across every stage (48 *minimum* in GL 3.3). So, while you may be able to *bind* 48 different textures at any given time, you would still have to split your draw into 3 passes to actually *apply* all 48.